# Laravel Eager loading with nested OR condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, query-builder

```
$query = LeadsModel::with(
                            array(
                                    'emails' => function ($q) use ($inputs) 
                                    {
                                        $q->orwhere('email','like',"%john%");
                                        $q->orwhere('email','like',"%mark%");
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                            ->whereHas
                            (
                                'emails', function ($q) use ($inputs) 
                                {
                                    $q->orwhere('email','like',"%john%");
                                    $q->orwhere('email','like','%mark%');
                                }
                            );

    $res = $query->get();

    display_output($res);
    return;
```

The code above only returns all record and no condition applied to the result. I am not sure what is wrong. What I want is to add conditions in the query for the child table associated with the parent but will return the parent and child data where the condition is applied

additional question:

- How can I add several OR condition in nested condition in eager loading?
- how can I control the precedence of the condition? lets say I will have 2 or 3 condition in the same precedence and I will have another condition with AND condition in a nested eager loading condition

**updated**

This still records all data, no condition applied.

```
    $query = LeadsModel::with(
                            array(
                                    'emails' => function ($q) use ($inputs) 
                                    {
                                        $q->orWhere('email','like',"%john%");
                                        $q->orWhere('email','like',"%james%");
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                            ->whereHas
                            (
                                'emails', function ($q) use ($inputs) 
                                {
                                    $q->where('email','like',"%john%")->orWhere('email','like','%james%');
                                }
                            );

    $res = $query->get();

    display_output($res);
    return;
```

in normal sql i guess it would be

select leads.*,lead_detail_emails.* from leads, lead_detail_emails where
leads.id = lead_detail_emails.lead_id and
(lead_detail_emails.email like '%john%' OR lead_detail_emails.email like '%james%');

Comment: You should add some example/code what you want to achieve

Comment: Please explain what exactly records you want to get from database - now it seems you want to get leadsmodel records that have emails like john or james and get for them related model emails that have also only name john or james.

Comment: i would like to get records from lead (parent of the email table) with condition of searching for john or james email

Comment: @Ponce Your guess about the query is wrong, check my edited answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need nested where:

```
whereHas('emails', function ($q)
{
    $q->where(function ($q) {
      $q->where('email','like',"%john%")
        ->orWhere('email','like','%mark%');
    });
})
```

This is example query for `whereHas` with pivot table (`belongsToMany`):

```
select * from `table` 
    where `table`.`deleted_at` is null 
        and (select count(*) from `related_table` inner join `pivot_table` on `related_table`.`id` = `pivot_table`.`related_id` 
    where `pivot_table`.`user_id` = `table`.`id` 
        and (`some_field` like ? or `some_field` like ?)) >= 1
```

Comment: that codes returns all record without conditions applied. i have updated the question with the complete eager loading.

Comment: sorry my mistake with comment above. this only returns John's record.

Comment: @Ponce You say that it will ignore the 2nd where, which is not true. So check your expectation and real result. This is what you need.

Comment: i need the john's or james' as for the result. i have added an sql query, probably something like that.

Comment: I know by the code you have, but do you know for sure? Have you checked the query that is executed and compared it's result to the same query run in the DB, outside the framework, so you are saying it ignores anything? **This only returns XYZ** might be true, because there are no other rows to return, while the query is OK.

Comment: Thanks Jarek, ya I had it 'mark' all along. now its working fine. sorry about that